# Using ruby to scrape Apple device identifiers and names with Nokogiri's css method

Tags: ios, css, ruby

**The Problem**

I am trying to create a ruby script that outputs the *Generation Name* of an Apple device when given the *Identifier*.

For example:
`ruby device_name.rb "iPad3,4"`
should output:
`iPad (4th generation)`

The data I need to do this is on this wiki page:
https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Unfortunately the tables are proving difficult to scrape.

I've had a tiny bit of success with the first table after inspecting elements in chrome so I could see the css structure.

For example, this will get me Identifiers in the Apple TV table:

```
doc.css("div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable")[0].children[Y].children[11].text
```

Y starts at 3 and then the Identifiers continue there on odd numbers until there are no more children.

If the Identifier matches the one inputted into ARGV[0], then I can ask for the Generation name with:

```
doc.css("div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable")[0].children[Y].children[1].text
```

So far so good, right?

But then the next table corresponding to Apple Watch and all the others after it confused me. This returns the entire next table.

```
doc.css("div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable")[1]
```

However, the same lookups don't work simply by changing to something like this:

```
doc.css("div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable")[0].children[3].children[11].text
```

Obviously there should be a different css path because there are more columns, but I can't get the same consistency or find a solid pattern in the other tables.

**Questions**

1. How can I get all of these identifiers and names programmatically?
2. Is there a better way to look these identifiers up? Maybe through an API?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda backwards and not necessarily pretty, but,

```
url = "http://web.archive.org/web/20170224033625/https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models" # couldn't access the site itself
req = HTTParty.get(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(req.response.body)
td = doc.css('td').detect { |td| td.text.index(input) }
model = td.parent.css('td')[0].text.strip
```

Comment: This is great, but appears to only work for the 1st identifier of each model. For example,"iPad2,1" returns "iPad 2", but "iPad2,2" returns "A1396", the A model. Any tweaks to make?